# From Nagios to check_mk config in three steps, how could I have done better?

Tags: vim, awk

I am setting up a new Nagios install using OMD & check_mk instead of doing everything by hand this time. The switches do not have proper hostnames in DNS so check_mk provides a method to specify the IP in the config file. I was converting the configuration file for some switches last night and I tried for a few minutes to do it one shot but then threw in the towel.

Example input:

```
define host{
    use         generic-switch
    host_name   BAR.MDF.MODEL
    alias       BAR.MDF.MODEL
    parents     FOO.MDF.MODEL.01
    address     10.1.1.1
    }
```

Required output:

```
ipaddresses = {
  "BAR.MDF.MODEL" : "10.1.1.1",
}
```

Here is what I did.

I knew that IPs were **always** after host_name so it is fairly safe/consistent

```
{ awk '/host_name/ || /address/ { print $2 }' < switch.cfg; } >> out.txt
```

which got me

```
BAR.MDF.MODEL
10.1.1.1
```

Then I did this

```
{ awk '!/^1/{ getline ip; print $0, ip; next }' < out.txt; } >> out2.txt
```

to get this:

```
BAR.MDF.MODEL 10.1.1.1
```

the rest of the formating was done in vim via 'norm' & macros etc

```
  "BAR.MDF.MODEL" : "10.1.1.1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if this could work for you. Only `awk`.

Assuming following data of `infile`

```
define host{
    use         generic-switch
    host_name   BAR.MDF.MODEL
    alias       BAR.MDF.MODEL
    parents     FOO.MDF.MODEL.01
    address     10.1.1.1
    }
define host{
    use         generic-switch
    host_name   BAR.MDF.MODEL.2
    alias       BAR.MDF.MODEL
    parents     FOO.MDF.MODEL.01
    address     10.1.1.2
    }
define host{
    use         generic-switch
    host_name   BAR.MDF.MODEL.3
    alias       BAR.MDF.MODEL
    parents     FOO.MDF.MODEL.01
    address     10.1.1.3
    }
```

Run this `awk` script:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { print "ipaddresses = {"; } 
    $1 == "host_name" { 
        hostname = "\"" $2 "\""; 
        next; 
    } 
    $1 == "address" { 
        address = "\"" $2 "\"";
        printf "\t%s : %s,\n", hostname, address;
    } 
    END {
        printf "}\n";
    }
' switch.cfg
```

That yields:

```
ipaddresses = {
        "BAR.MDF.MODEL" : "10.1.1.1",
        "BAR.MDF.MODEL.2" : "10.1.1.2",
        "BAR.MDF.MODEL.3" : "10.1.1.3",
}
```

Comment: Is `$1 == "host_name" {` shorthand for `if ($1 == "host_name") {`? Am I reading that right? It evals to true then variable "hostname" is set to $2? Sort of like `[[ -e file ]] && rm file` in bash?

Comment: oops. I didn't think to mention it...this does work for the first host definition in switch.cfg but there are 39 of them. :s

Comment: @Ryan: Updated answer. To your first question, yes. If the condition succeeds, execute instructions inside curly braces.

Comment: I actually thought while taking a walk today...hrmm wasn't there a break or an exit in there that I could get rid of. I wonder if that would work. Came back to try it and saw your update. Thanks a lot. Definitely learned a couple things here I will use again later.